# How to count '\n' in an UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I got a headache trying to count returns (\n) in my UITextView. As you'll soon realise, I'm a bloody beginner and here is my theory of what I've come up with, but there are many gaps...

```
- (IBAction)countReturns:(id)sender {

int returns;

while ((textView = getchar()) != endOfString [if there is such a thing?])
{
   if (textView = getchar()) == '\n') {
   returns++;
   }
}

NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Number of returns: %d", returns];
    numberReturns.text = newText;

    [newText release];
    }
```

I checked other questions on here, but people are usually (in my eyes) lost in some details which I don't understand. Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply

```
UITextView *theview; //remove this line, and change future theview to your veiw
NSString *thestring; //for storing a string from your view
int returnint = 0;
thestring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[theview text]];

for (int temp = 0; temp < [thestring length]; temp++){ //run through the string
if ([thestring characterAtIndex: temp] == '\n')
    returnint++;
}
```

Comment: Does `\n` count as 1 character?

Comment: The \indicates an escape sequence. \n is indeed a single character.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful and so graceful programmed. I know, I know, people must think this is bloody easy, but I really like it. I shall commit this to my memory. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *newlines = [textView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

int returns = ([newlines count]-1)
```

Should work. Keep in mind this isn't such a great idea if you have a gia-normous string, but it's quick, dirty and easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of ways to do that. Here is one:

```
NSString *str = @"FooBar\n\nBaz...\n\nABC\n";
NSString *tmpStr = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
NSInteger count = [str length] - [tmpStr length];
NSLog(@"Count: %d", count);
```